Missing $i$ in Feynman Propagator Minkowski Space
I'm Trying to resolve the following equation in Minkowski Space
$$    \left(\Delta_{x}-m^2\right)G(x^{\mu},y^{\mu})= - \frac{\delta^{(D)}(x^{\mu}-y^{\mu})}{\sqrt{g(x)}}$$
where
$$    \Delta_{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g(x)}}\partial_{x^i}\left(\sqrt{g(x)}g^{ij}\delta_{x^j}\right)$$
But when I solve it I get the following integral
$$  G(x^{\mu},0) =  \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{(p_{0})^2-(\omega_{p})^2+i\epsilon}e^{ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}$$
But in different books and articles I find the propagator to be equal to
$$  G(x^{\mu},0) =  \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{-i}{(p_{0})^2-(\omega_{p})^2+i\epsilon}e^{ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}$$
All that I do to approach this problem is making use of Fourier Transforms, so I don't really see where the $-i$ comes from

Since you are working in Minkowski spacetime, there doesn't seem to be any reason to carry the metric around so much.

This is just an issue with your definition of the propagator. Some authors define $G$ as
$$(\Delta_x - m^2)G(x,y) = \delta(x,y),$$
some as
$$(\Delta_x - m^2)G(x,y) = -\delta(x,y),$$
some as
$$(\Delta_x - m^2)G(x,y) = - i \delta(x,y),$$
and you get the idea. Naturally, different definitions will add a factor of $\pm 1$ or $\pm i$ relative to each other. The important thing is that you choose one convention and stick to it, and be aware of these differences when checking other references.
I should mention that, if $G$ is the Feynman propagator, then we have
$$\langle 0 | T \phi(x) \phi(y) | 0 \rangle = \alpha G(x,y),$$
and the value of $\alpha$ depends on the particular convention of the author.

But in the long term it does affect doesn't it? i.e. I'm doing some expansions of $G(x,y)$ that are affected by that differnece between having or not the i

@OswaldoRO You can choose whichever convention you want, as long as you are consistent with it. In quantum field theory, what truly matters is not $G(x,y)$, but $\langle 0 | T \phi(x) \phi(y) | 0 \rangle$. However, if your formulas are written in terms of $G$, that constant $\alpha$ (which depends on convention) will play a role

Ultimately, the convention is meaningless. However, it is fundamental that you are completely consistent with it. If you are taking formulae from a book, follow that book's conventions

I don't know why anyone downvoted this answer. This is the exact right answer.

+1, and just to emphasize for the OP, keeping track of conventions, especially when you are comparing sources that use different conventions, is a major source of headaches in real physics research. So make sure you understand exactly what conventions your sources are using! Alternatively, if you are just trying to get a big picture and not a detailed calculation, don't get hung up on details like this because they can be a distraction from the big picture. (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/on-compilation-errors-in-mathematical-reading-and-how-to-resolve-them/)
